# unable to install cpupower for kernel 5.13.0-52

Tags: kernel, power-management, shutdown, cpu

I need to install cpupower to force my cpu to a constant lower state. I can do this easily in windows using the power management control panel and setting the min/max cpu percentage. I have not found an easy way to do this in Ubuntu unfortunately. I would like to set the CPU lower as it is summer time and my CPU easily reaches above 100c where it will shut it's self down without warning. it is not a "shutting down" through software, it is sudden instant off. If I force a constant lower freq it runs cool, and the performance is still reasonable.

I have tried cpufreq-set to powersave, but this does not lock the processor to a lower level it is only ondemand.

I have tried cpupower, but it refuses to install on my kernel. It says "You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel: Unable to locate package linux-tools-5.13.0-52-generic, linux-cloud-tools-5.13.0-52-generic.

when I attempt to install this, it says Unable to locate package linux-tools-5.13.0-52-generic

please help save my laptop and my work. thank you.

Comment: What processor make and model? do: `grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo`. What CPU frequency scaling driver? do: `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver`.

Comment: What OS & release are you using?   You mention only a kernel that is in it's last days/hours of support, as fully-upgraded systems will no longer be using it; are you using Ubuntu?   (if using Ubuntu 21.10 - I'd suggest *release-upgrading* asap - https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/)